# ¿Cómo cambio el valor de una varible a través de un botón sin actualizar la página?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un valor predefinido que muestro en pantalla usando `document.write` y me gustaría que al pulsar un botón me reste 1.

Este es mi código:

```js
var municion  = 99;
    document.write(municion);


do{
    function pulsarboton(municion = municion--){
    }
pulsarboton();
}while(municion = 0);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="boton" type="button" value="Resta 1" onclick="pulsarboton()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave está en usar una variable global para luego ir actualizando su valor en cada pulsación del botón. Luego, lo que hago es insertarlo dentro de un `<p>` que definí para mostrar la munición.

```js
//Definimos la variable como una variable global para que sea plenamente accesible.
municion  = 99;
//Insertamos en un primer momento el valor inicial de la variable.
miMunicion.innerHTML = 'Munición restante: ' + municion;  
   
function pulsarboton () {
  //Le restamos 1 a la variable global.
  municion--;
  //Insertamos dentro de un párrafo la munición actualizada tras pulsar el botón.
  miMunicion.innerHTML = 'Munición restante: ' + municion;    
}
```

```css
#miMunicion {
  color: red;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="boton" type="button" value="Resta 1" onclick="pulsarboton()">
    <div><p id="miMunicion"></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, en tu ejemplo no se muestra el valor inicial de la variable. Creo que es parte esencial de la pregunta. Pequeño `bug` que podrías corregir. Saludos

Comment: Tienes razón, he actualizado la respuesta para que se muestre.